# How to create 30 second automated audio clip in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio

I'm working on a side project for fun casual use

In android studio I'm trying to implement a button click that starts an automatic 30 second audio recording that the user can do or say whatever in that period of time.

After the clip has finished it auto plays back and gives the ability to save or download directly to the device

I haven't started yet, I was more curious as to what particular methods in the API i should be looking into???

Any advice would be amazing thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 100;
private Sync mSync;
private boolean mIsRecording = false;
private long mStartTime = 0;
private long mStopTime = 0;
private String mFileName;

private void startRecord() {
    startRecording();
    mSync = new Sync(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!mIsRecording||!isAdded())
                return;
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (currentTime-mStartTime>AppConstants.MAX_RECORD_DURATION_S*1000){
                stopRecord();
                updateLayoutVisibility();
                return;                                 
            }
            String str = getString(R.string.recording_template,(currentTime-mStartTime)/1000,AppConstants.MAX_RECORD_DURATION_S);
            mTextSeconds.setText(str);
            mSync.next();
        }
    },UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mSync.now();
    mLayoutButtonsStartRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mLayoutButtonsRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}


private void stopRecord() {
    mSync.stop();
    mIsRecording = false;
    mStopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mMediaRecorder.stop();
    mMediaRecorder.release();
    mMediaRecorder = null;      
}

private void startRecording() {
    if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
        mMediaRecorder.release();
    }
    mFileName = getTempRecordFileName();
    if (mFileName==null){
        dismiss();
        return;
    }
    mIsRecording = true;
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);

    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
        mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                R.string.error_failed_start_recording, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed start recorder", e);
        mMediaRecorder.release();
        mMediaRecorder = null;
        dismiss();
        return;
    }
}

private class Sync{
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable task;
    private long period;

    public Sync(Runnable task,long period){
        this.task = task;
        this.period = period;
        handler.removeCallbacks(task);
    }
    public void now(){
        task.run();
    }

    public void next(){
        handler.postDelayed(task, period);
    }
    public void stop(){
        handler.removeCallbacks(task);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause(); 
    if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
        mMediaRecorder.release();
        mMediaRecorder = null;
    }
    if (mSync!=null){
       mSync.stop();
    }

}
```